# As a result I redirected to my ID editing form using twig and php

Tags: php, twig

I am learning to use twig and I do not know how to redirect to an editing path through ID

In pure PHP it would be like this for example:

```
<a href="update.php?id='.$row["id"].'">edit</a>
```

In twig to redirect to a location I use my route and the URL filter for example:

```
<a href="{{'admin' | url}}">Back</a>
```

How do I achieve this: `<a href="update.php?id='.$row["id"].'">editar</a>` but using twig.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have defined the route with the parameters in your routing file.

So if you want to generate url for the route: `/update.php?id={id}` then you can pass the `id` parameter like this:

`{{ url('update.php', {'id': '. $row['id'] .'}) }}`

[Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#templating-pages)